# How to make infinite flip out of the code below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to tweak the flip javascript in this link http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html so that it will flip to the third content or won't referse flip to the first content

```
var init = function() {
    var card = document.getElementById('card');

    document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
        card.toggleClassName('flipped');
    }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: Do you need to have 3 cards, then flip to the middle one, and then flip to the last one and end it?

Comment: Yes, I'll need three or more cards, that flip to the next card, something like loop.
How do I tweak the code above?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't any clue how to do it. still in the process of learning js.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></kbd>

The contents of each element should be stored separately in the HTML, and retrieved when needed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face face1"></div>
        <div class="face face2"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="store">
        <li>
            <div class="content content1">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content2">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content3">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content4">4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Answer copied and edited from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351420/2260614)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want the click event to happen once. If that's the case, and you're alright using jQuery, the jQuery 'one' function should be what you're looking for.

```
$( "#flip" ).one( "click", function() {
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
});
```

Comment: no not once, three or more cards, that flip to the next card,  and the last card flips to the first card, something like loop. How do I tweak the code above?

Comment: I haven't included all of the fancy transforms, but I think that this is the basics of what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/Barbacoa/7p6EC/2/