# How to do a page flip-like transform: rotateY?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/DaE3V/

I just started to learn about css animations...

Im trying to do a `transform: rotateY(180deg);` but instead of just rotating, I wanted to flip it, kinda like a page of a book...

it that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can  try this: http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/demo.html

Comment: Also try this http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect

Comment: I dont really want the paper effect, what I actually want to do is do a 180 rotation, but instead of it landing in the same spot, I would like it to land about the same of its width to the left. Like how a hard cover of a book would do.

Comment: Please refer this link:[Page Flip](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23435478/2260614 might help..

Comment: @Shadow Yes, thats where I actually learned about rotate. But is there anyway to rotate it as if one of the sides were glued to the background. I hope im making sense, Im really having a hard time explaining.

Comment: @ Pa3k.m:what do you mean by one side glued to the background?Is [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect) what you want?

Comment: @Shadow http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DRestaurantMenu/ Kinda like how the front page worked.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Comment: @Pa3k.m:Not able to  open the link

Comment: @Shadow nevermind, I already solved my problem with `transform-origin` Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with pure CSS. But as it seems that you're using jQuery, and there is a bunch of plug-ins you can use to achieve things like that.
Here's a couple of links to check out:

[jQuery flip plug-ins](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/flip/)
[imBookFlip (might fit your needs pretty well)](http://plugins.jquery.com/imbookflip/)